# JPA annotation for default value for a column having type BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In one of my model taking column value as BigDecimal, i need to set default value as 0 at jpa level.How would i do that?

```
@Entity
public class Myclass{
@Column
private BigDecimal value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `columnDefinition` property to tell ORM about the default value for the field. Actually thats an implicit way of having this functionality.

```
@Column(name="value", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '0.00'")
private BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

Along with that, you could initialize the field with `BigDecimal.ZERO` that will occupy the same purpose when you will create `new` Object from that entity before persist.

Answer (score 2):

use hibernate annotation check [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value)

```
@ColumnDefault("0")
private BigDecimal value;
```

Comment: In my case it was like this @ColumnDefault("1") private int unreadPost = 1; Because int has a default value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Entity
public class Myclass{
    @Column
    private BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

IMHO this code more clearly shows your intentions than magic annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your setter method and set default value other wise set value in database column a default value.
public void setvalue(BigDecimal  value){if(value==null){this.value=0;}}

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this code and found out that add the `new` keyword otherwise you'll have NullPointerException

```
@Entity
public class Myclass{
    @Column
    private BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("0"); //
    private BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```